# How to connect Ubuntu that on Hyper-V to phone that connected using USB?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-virtualization

I google this and all the solutions I found are not working (chatGPT also doesn't know).

I use Ubuntu over Hyper-V with the android studio to develop something on my Android phone.
I can't find a way to connect the phone to the Android studio ( that is on Ubuntu) for run debug

any suggestions?